# iam:PutRolePolicy User: xxx is not authorized to perform: iam:PutRolePolicy on resource: role yyy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have a cloudformation stack to create my codepipeline/codebuild resources etc. When I try to run it, I get:

> iam:PutRolePolicy User: arn:aws:sts::0000000000:assumed-role/aaaaaaaaaa/AWSCloudFormation is not authorized to perform: iam:PutRolePolicy on resource: role bbbbbbbbbb

Whats wrong? I already have a policy like:

```
- Effect: Allow
  Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/*'
  Action:
  - 'iam:GetRole'
  - 'iam:CreateRole'
  - 'iam:DeleteRole'
  - 'iam:PassRole'
  - 'iam:AttachRolePolicy'
  - 'iam:DetachRolePolicy'
  - 'iam:DeleteRolePolicy'
  - 'iam:PutRolePolicy'
```

My stack YAML

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Description: 'Skynet stack for CodePipeline'

Parameters:
  PipelineName:
    Type: String
    Description: Pipeline Name (Lower case only, since S3 bucket names can only have lowercase)
    Default: skynet-pipeline
  GitHubOwner:
    Type: String
    Description: GitHub Owner
    Default: 2359media
  GitHubRepo:
    Type: String
    Description: GitHub Repo
    Default: 'skynet'
  GitHubBranch:
    Type: String
    Description: GitHub Branch
    Default: master
  GitHubToken:
    Type: String
    Description: GitHub Token
    NoEcho: true

Resources:
  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref PipelineName
      RoleArn: !GetAtt [PipelineRole, Arn]
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref PipelineArtifactStore
        Type: S3
      DisableInboundStageTransitions: []
      Stages:
        - Name: GitHubSource
          Actions:
          - Name: Source
            ActionTypeId:
              Category: Source
              Owner: ThirdParty
              Version: 1
              Provider: GitHub
            Configuration:
              Owner: !Ref GitHubOwner
              Repo: !Ref GitHubRepo
              Branch: !Ref GitHubBranch
              OAuthToken: !Ref GitHubToken
            OutputArtifacts:
              - Name: SourceCode
        - Name: Build
          Actions:
          - Name: Lambda
            InputArtifacts:
              - Name: SourceCode
            OutputArtifacts:
              - Name: LambdaPackage
            ActionTypeId:
              Category: Build
              Owner: AWS
              Version: 1
              Provider: CodeBuild
            Configuration:
              ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuildLambda
        - Name: CreateChangeSet
          Actions:
          - Name: Lambda
            InputArtifacts:
              - Name: LambdaPackage
            OutputArtifacts:
              - Name: LambdaDeployment
            ActionTypeId:
              Category: Deploy
              Owner: AWS
              Version: 1
              Provider: CloudFormation
            Configuration:
              ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_REPLACE
              ChangeSetName: !Sub
                - '${PipelineName}-lambda'
                - {PipelineName: !Ref PipelineName}
              RoleArn: !GetAtt [CloudFormationRole, Arn]
              StackName: !Sub
                - '${PipelineName}-lambda'
                - {PipelineName: !Ref PipelineName}
              TemplatePath: 'LambdaPackage::SkynetLambdaPackaged.yml'
        - Name: ExecuteChangeSet
          Actions:
          - Name: Lambda
            ActionTypeId:
              Category: Deploy
              Owner: AWS
              Version: 1
              Provider: CloudFormation
            Configuration:
              ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE
              ChangeSetName: !Sub
                - '${PipelineName}-lambda'
                - {PipelineName: !Ref PipelineName}
              StackName: !Sub
                - '${PipelineName}-lambda'
                - {PipelineName: !Ref PipelineName}

  CodeBuildLambda:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub '${PipelineName}-lambda'
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: aws/codebuild/nodejs:7.0.0
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        EnvironmentVariables:
          - Name: S3_BUCKET
            Value: !Ref PipelineArtifactStore
      ServiceRole: !Ref CodeBuildRole
      Source:
        BuildSpec: 'lambda/buildspec.yml'
        Type: CODEPIPELINE

  PipelineArtifactStore:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub '${PipelineName}-artifacts'
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled

  CodeBuildRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub '${PipelineName}-codebuild'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: codebuild.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub '${PipelineName}-codebuild'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:*'
                Action:
                - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
              - Effect: Allow
                Resource:
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-${AWS::Region}-*/*'
                  - !Sub
                    - '${PipelineArtifactStoreArn}/*'
                    - {PipelineArtifactStoreArn: !GetAtt [PipelineArtifactStore, Arn]}
                Action:
                  - 's3:GetObject'
                  - 's3:GetObjectVersion'
                  - 's3:PutObject'

  CloudFormationRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub '${PipelineName}-cloudformation'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: cloudformation.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaExecute'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub '${PipelineName}-cloudformation'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Resource: '*'
                Action:
                - 's3:GetObject'
                - 's3:GetObjectVersion'
                - 's3:GetBucketVersioning'
              - Effect: Allow
                Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline*'
                Action:
                - 's3:PutObject'
              - Effect: Allow
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:*'
                Action:
                - 'lambda:*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}::*'
                Action:
                - 'apigateway:*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Resource: '*'
                Action:
                - 'lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping'
                - 'lambda:DeleteEventSourceMapping'
                - 'lambda:GetEventSourceMapping'
              - Effect: Allow
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/*'
                Action:
                - 'iam:GetRole'
                - 'iam:CreateRole'
                - 'iam:DeleteRole'
                - 'iam:PassRole'
                - 'iam:AttachRolePolicy'
                - 'iam:DetachRolePolicy'
                - 'iam:DeleteRolePolicy'
                - 'iam:PutRolePolicy'
              - Effect: Allow
                Resource: '*'
                Action:
                - 'iam:PassRole'
              - Effect: Allow
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:cloudformation:${AWS::Region}:aws:transform/Serverless-2016-10-31'
                Action:
                - 'cloudformation:CreateChangeSet'

  PipelineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub '${PipelineName}-pipeline'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [codepipeline.amazonaws.com]
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: SkynetPipeline
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Action:
                - 's3:GetObject'
                - 's3:GetObjectVersion'
                - 's3:GetBucketVersioning'
                Effect: 'Allow'
                Resource: '*'
              - Action:
                - 's3:PutObject'
                Effect: 'Allow'
                Resource:
                - !GetAtt [PipelineArtifactStore, Arn]
              - Action:
                - 'codecommit:CancelUploadArchive'
                - 'codecommit:GetBranch'
                - 'codecommit:GetCommit'
                - 'codecommit:GetUploadArchiveStatus'
                - 'codecommit:UploadArchive'
                Effect: 'Allow'
                Resource: '*'
              - Action:
                - 'codedeploy:CreateDeployment'
                - 'codedeploy:GetApplicationRevision'
                - 'codedeploy:GetDeployment'
                - 'codedeploy:GetDeploymentConfig'
                - 'codedeploy:RegisterApplicationRevision'
                Effect: 'Allow'
                Resource: '*'
              - Action:
                - 'elasticbeanstalk:*'
                - 'ec2:*'
                - 'elasticloadbalancing:*'
                - 'autoscaling:*'
                - 'cloudwatch:*'
                - 's3:*'
                - 'sns:*'
                - 'cloudformation:*'
                - 'rds:*'
                - 'sqs:*'
                - 'ecs:*'
                - 'iam:PassRole'
                Effect: 'Allow'
                Resource: '*'
              - Action:
                - 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
                - 'lambda:ListFunctions'
                Effect: 'Allow'
                Resource: '*'
              - Action:
                - 'opsworks:CreateDeployment'
                - 'opsworks:DescribeApps'
                - 'opsworks:DescribeCommands'
                - 'opsworks:DescribeDeployments'
                - 'opsworks:DescribeInstances'
                - 'opsworks:DescribeStacks'
                - 'opsworks:UpdateApp'
                - 'opsworks:UpdateStack'
                Effect: 'Allow'
                Resource: '*'
              - Action:
                - 'cloudformation:CreateStack'
                - 'cloudformation:DeleteStack'
                - 'cloudformation:DescribeStacks'
                - 'cloudformation:UpdateStack'
                - 'cloudformation:CreateChangeSet'
                - 'cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet'
                - 'cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet'
                - 'cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet'
                - 'cloudformation:SetStackPolicy'
                - 'cloudformation:ValidateTemplate'
                - 'iam:PassRole'
                Effect: 'Allow'
                Resource: '*'
              - Action:
                - 'codebuild:BatchGetBuilds'
                - 'codebuild:StartBuild'
                Effect: 'Allow'
                Resource: '*'
```

Comment: When you say "run it", do you mean run your created pipeline, or when you try to create your CloudFormation stack?

Comment: Have you tried `Resource: '*'` for your IAM section of your policy rather than trying to limit it to roles?

Comment: @MattHouser updating my cloudformation stack in this case

Comment: @MattHouser I tried deleting the entire stack ... but it seems it deleted the cloudformation role and I am no longer able to proceed ... seems like something is wrong somewhere? Why is it executing in a role it created?

Comment: I have manually deleted the resources. Seems like either that or changing the IAM resource to * solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like either manually deleting stack and re-creating or changing IAM resource to `*` solves the issue.

Comment: deleting the stack helped!

Answer (score 0):

In my I need to use aws sts [assume-role](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html) first